# Logarithm question involving different base

Tags: logarithms

Calculate the values of $z$ for which $\log_3 z = 4\log_z3$.

Comment: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself. Also, many would consider your post rude because it is a command ("Calculate"), not a request for help, so please consider rewriting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\log_3 z = 4\log_z3 \Rightarrow \dfrac{\log z}{\log 3}=4\dfrac{\log 3}{\log z}$$

**Answer** *(don't look until you try the hint)*
$$\color{lightgrey}{\dfrac{\log z}{\log 3}=4\dfrac{\log 3}{\log z}\Rightarrow (\log z )^2=4(\log 3)^2 \Rightarrow \log z =2\log 3 \Rightarrow \log z =\log 3^2 \Rightarrow z = 3^2}$$

$\color{lightgrey}{\text{Therefore} \ z=9.}$

Answer (score 2):

Hint : use the formula for the change of base $\log_b(x) = \frac{\log_k(x)}{\log_k(b)}$ to change the base $z$ of the expression on the right.

Comment: what is the value for k ?

Comment: it is arbitrary. In this case just choose it to be $10$ so the equation is equivalent to $\log_b(x) = \frac{\log(x)}{\log(b)}$ , since the $\log$ function is in Base $10$ by definition.

Answer (score 0):

hint :

$$\frac{\log (z)}{\log (3)}=4\frac{\log (3)}{\log (z)}$$

$$(\log (z))^2=4(\log (3))^2$$

Comment: Please use `\log`. Writing `log` is interpreted as a product of variables named "`l`", "`o`", and "`g`", just as it is when you write `ab` in math mode, for example. The name of the function should be upright and have proper spacing, and that is what `\log` does. There are similar commands `\sin`, `\cos`, `\exp`, etc.

Comment: @ZevChonoles:sorry about the wrong 
next time iam going to write correctly

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\log z}{\log 3}=4\frac{\log 3}{\log z}$

$(\log z)^2=(\log 3)(4\log 3)$

$\log z=\sqrt{(\log3)(4\log 3)}$

$ z=10 \exp\left(\sqrt{4(\log 3)^2}\right)$

Comment: Please use `\log`. Writing `log` is interpreted as a product of variables named "`l`", "`o`", and "`g`", just as it is when you write `ab` in math mode, for example. The name of the function should be upright and have proper spacing, and that is what `\log` does. There are similar commands `\sin`, `\cos`, `\exp`, etc.